# Dynamic list properties of a class and ask for theses values

Tags: python, class, properties

I'm quite new to python, and try to write a module/

I try to request dynamically all attributes/properties of my class and then I want to ask for the value, but I cannot managed to have the result I want.

Goal : have a list of properties. in this exemple it would be 
name and author

And after ask for these values
name : 'my first app'
author : 'me'.

if I run this code, I will raise an exception on line 39 :

`request =  my_app + '.' + attribute
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Application' and 'str'`

I tried to use `str(my_app)`, but of course it doesn't work because the reference to the object is gone.

The first request with `__dict__` might be fine, but what I need is to have `author` and `name` as `dict.keys`, and not `_Application__author` and `_Application__name`.

This is a simple exemple for asking, but in my module I have a lot of properties.

Maybe someone have a clue?

```
class Application(object):
    def __init__(self, name,author=''):
        self.__name = name
        self.__author = author

    # ----------- NAME -------------
    @property
    def name(self):
        "Current name of the model"
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    @name.deleter
    def name(self):
        pass

    # ----------- AUTHOR -------------
    @property
    def author(self):
        "Current author of the model"
        return self.__author

    @author.setter
    def author(self, author):
        self.__author = author

    @author.deleter
    def author(self):
        pass

my_app = Application('my first app',author='me',)

print my_app.__dict__

for attribute in dir(my_app):
    if not attribute.startswith('__'):
        if not attribute.startswith('_'):
            if not attribute == 'instances':
                request =  my_app + '.' + attribute
```

Result

```
{'_Application__author': 'me', '_Application__name': 'my first app'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/reno/Desktop/testtt.py", line 42, in <module>
    request =  my_app + '.' + attribute
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Application' and 'str'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/reno/Desktop/testtt.py"]
[dir: /Users/reno/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is to use the `getattr` method.

I just replaced the last line with this one and it works like a charm.

```
                print attribute , ':' , getattr(my_app, attribute)
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_app` is an instance of `Application`, its *type* is `Application`. On the other hand, `'.'` is a String by *type*.

Now, when you add two things with `+`, Python needs to know how to add those things. For numbers it knows how to do that. For strings it also knows this: It will just concatenate them.

But there is no addition defined between an `Application` and a `string`. Therefore you get the error.

Also, why do you have a comma behing the last argument of

```
my_app = Application('my first app',author='me',)
```

?

Comment: I knew that the addition wasn't the right method, but it was to explain what I wanted to do.

Comment: The comma is an oversight because I remove a lot of attributes of my class to be as short as possible and focus on the problem… Tx @Konstantin for having a look on my problem !

Comment: @reno- I think you question was fine, I just did not read it properly :)